# Why ROS Topic should get XMLRPC address:port but ROS Service doesn't?

Tags: ros, xmlrpc, topic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [ROS Introduction (Radu Bogdan Rusu)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/CoTeSys-ROS-School?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=ros_tutorial.pdf) in Events/CoTeSys-OS-School.

This is ROS Topic mechanism:
[image: image description]

I can see in step 2, Listener get Talker's XML/RPC's address:port.

This is ROS Service mechanism:
[image: image description]

I can see in step 2, Listener get Talker's XML/RPC's data address:port.

My question is why ROS topic should let Listener get its XML/RPC's address:port but ROS Service doesn't?

By the way:

1.what is second picture's step 3? Is step 3 is Listener making a data port connection(foo:3456) to Talker?

2.Is "foo" a IP address?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12882/why-ros-topic-should-get-xmlrpc-address:port-but-ros-service-doesn%27t?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishers have an XMLRPC interface for getting the connection information, so that subscribers can request the most appropriate transport (TCP or UDP), and get an appropriate response. Since services only have one underlying transport, this extra layer is unnecessary.

1. I have no idea where step 3 went.
2. "foo" is the ROS_HOSTNAME of the machine that talker is running on. In most cases this just the machine's hostname, but it may also be a string representation of an IP.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-10**:
Is step 3 is Listener making a data port connection(foo:3456) to Talker?

**Comment by [Edward](https://answers.ros.org/users/29319/edward/) on 2018-08-12**:
And a little more inaccuracy in the pictures. In the first picture, in step 3, connect ("scan", TCP) should be connect ("bar", TCP). This led me to a small misconception, until I learned the original page here:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview